# Creating a unified search function for a binary search tree

Tags: c++, search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create a search function in a binary search tree that can be used by both the insert and search functions.

I tried passing my cursor as a reference

```
template<class key_type, class data_type>
bool binary_tree<key_type, data_type>::internal_search(node *& cursor, key_type query) {
    if (cursor == NULL) {
        return false;
    }else if (cursor->key == query) {
        return true;
    }
    if (cursor->key < query) {
        internal_search(cursor->left, query);
    }
    else {
        internal_search(cursor->right, query);
    }
}
```

Here is the insert function I'm trying to use it in

```
template<class key_type, class data_type>
void binary_tree<key_type, data_type>::insert(key_type key_in, data_type data_in) {
    node * local_cursor = start;
    if (!internal_search(local_cursor, key_in)) {
        local_cursor = new node;
        local_cursor->key = key_in;
        local_cursor->data = data_in;
        local_cursor->left = NULL;
        local_cursor->right = NULL;
        size++;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "entry already present" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the search function I'm trying to use it in

```
template<class key_type, class data_type>
data_type binary_tree<key_type, data_type>::search(key_type query) {
    node * local_cursor = start;
    if (internal_search(local_cursor, query)) {
        return local_cursor->data;
    }
    std::cout << "search query not found" << std::endl;
}
```

Neither passing through as a reference or returning as a value have worked

I don't understand why when I run this code the `start` pointer is always `NULL` when inserting a new value into the binary search tree.

I also tried rewriting the code with the `internal_search` function returning a node pointer but that didn't work either.

Why does `start` point to `NULL` everytime instead of the new node I assigned it to?

here's the header if that might help

```
#pragma once

template <class key_type, class data_type>
class binary_tree
{
private:
    struct node {
        key_type key;
        data_type data;
        node * left;
        node * right;
    };
    node * start;
    int size;

    bool internal_search(node *, key_type);

    void print_preorder(node * cursor = start);
    void file_preorder( std::ofstream&, node *);

    void file_inorder(std::ofstream&, node *);
    void print_inorder_pri(node *);

    void print_postorder(node *);
    void file_postorder(std::ofstream&, node *);

public:
    binary_tree();
    void insert(key_type);
    void remove();
    bool is_empty();
    data_type search(key_type);
    void print_preorder();
    void file_preorder(std::ofstream&);
    void print_inorder();
    void file_inorder(std::ofstream&);
    void print_postorder();
    void file_postorder(std::ofstream&);
    void print_level();
    bool load_file(std::string);
    void save_file(std::string);
    ~binary_tree();
};
```

Comment: Please, debug this step-wise for a small sample to find out what is going wrong where. Please, watch the warnings your compiler is probably emitting (or raise the warning level to get warnings). When I started with looking at `binary_tree<key_type, data_type>::internal_search()`, I realized that not every code path ends in `return`. (At this point, I stopped looking and started complaining. ;-)) If I compile such code in VS2013 (with my usual project settings) I get an error (and even cannot run that code).

Comment: With gcc 7.3.0 (++17), I got other compilation errors. Moreover, some function implementations are missing, not only main()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trivial modifications (including the one related to @Scheff's comment), I got it compiled.

However, `start` was effectively always equal to NULL. 
I discovered that the problem was that `ìnternal_search` was always returning NULL, i.e.
the value of the node* before node creation and not the address of node* where to create the new node. Therefore, it was needed to replace `(node* &)` by `(node** &)`.

Here is the code that seems to work, (with a `main()` for test) at least for the simple test `search`that was causing problem to the PO. Some work must be done to improve (e.g. a recursive `insert`) and complete the code (e.g. to delete the object binary_tree) but this is out of the scope of the question (fortunately!).

```
#include    <iostream>

template <class key_type, class data_type>
class binary_tree
{
private:
    struct node {
    key_type key;
    data_type data;
    node* left = NULL;
    node* right = NULL;
    };
    node* start = NULL;
    int size = 0;

    bool internal_search(node** &cursor, key_type);

    //void print_preorder(node * cursor = start);
    //void file_preorder( std::ofstream&, node *);

    void file_inorder(std::ofstream&, node *);
    void print_inorder_pri(node *);

    void print_postorder(node *);
    void file_postorder(std::ofstream&, node *);

public:
    binary_tree() {};
    void insert(key_type, data_type);
    void remove();
    bool is_empty();
    data_type search(key_type);
    //void print_preorder();
    void file_preorder(std::ofstream&);
    void print_inorder();
    void file_inorder(std::ofstream&);
    void print_postorder();
    void file_postorder(std::ofstream&);
    void print_level();
    bool load_file(std::string);
    void save_file(std::string);

    void print_start () {std::cout << start << "\n";}   // Added

    //~binary_tree();
};

template<class key_type, class data_type>
bool binary_tree<key_type, data_type>::internal_search (node** &cursor, key_type query) {
    if (*cursor == NULL) {
        return false;
     } else if ((*cursor)->key == query) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((*cursor)->key < query) {
        cursor = &((*cursor)->left);
        return internal_search(cursor, query);
    } else {
        cursor = &((*cursor)->right);
        return internal_search(cursor, query);
    }
}

template<class key_type, class data_type>
void binary_tree<key_type, data_type>::insert(key_type key_in, data_type data_in) {
    node** local_cursor = &start;
    if (!internal_search(local_cursor, key_in)) {
        *local_cursor = new node;
        (*local_cursor)->key = key_in;
        (*local_cursor)->data = data_in;
        size++;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "entry already present" << std::endl;
    }
}

template<class key_type, class data_type>
data_type binary_tree<key_type, data_type>::search(key_type query) {
    node** local_cursor = &start;
    if (internal_search(local_cursor, query)) {
        return (*local_cursor)->data;
    }
    std::cout << "search query not found" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    binary_tree<int,int> tree;
    tree.insert (0,0);
    tree.insert (2,3);
    tree.insert (-2,3);
    tree.insert (-1,-1);
    std::cout << "start = ";
    tree.print_start();

    std::cout << tree.search(2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```